# What is com.android.server.networkpermissioncontrol?

Tags: android, performance, security, networking, mobile

I notice this app running in my new device and it's using my mobile Data does anyone know what it does?

I've tried looking up what it is for but no result I have a new device and it recently runs in my background and uses my mobile Data like only kilobytes sisiskskskwkkskwka8skwkais8wkskwww